# How to dynamically generate an Image to be used as the Meta og:image url?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image-processing, heroku, koa

I'm interested in learning how to dynamically generate an og:image. Take for example the site Molly and Michael Seibel's profile page.

His profile page: https://molly.com/michael

His page has a unique meta `og:image` which makes sharing this page much friendlier with link previews in iMessage, FB, Twitter, LinkedIn etc...

```
<meta content="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/molly-assets-prod/michael-card.png" property="og:image">
```

[image: Custom OG IMAGE for url]

With my app built with Node.js, KOA, React and hosted on heroku, how can I dynamically generate a unique `og:image` per each of my user's profile page where I have their name and photo?

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-helmet for that: https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet

Comment: Thanks but that would require server side rendering for the og tags which create react app does not support.

Comment: `react-helmet` doesn't show images in `og:image`